# Heroku can't find SecureRandom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My heroku app is crashing because it can't find the module 'SecureRandom'. I am specifying my Ruby version in the gemfile, and my computer, gemfile and Heroku all seem to match Ruby version numbers, though not the patch numbers.

Other posts have suggested pointing usr/bin/heroku to a specific Ruby file, but I'm not sure how to do that (I have no Heroku bin in my app). This does seem like a Ruby version error. How can I try to fix this?

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'SecureRandom'

  ...
end
```

Heroku log:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': No such file to load -- SecureRandom (LoadError)
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
```

Command line:

```
/ $ heroku run ruby -v
Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.9318
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux]

/ $ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was under the impression modules and classes were declared in mixed case, as stated in sites like this: http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7. But apparently, one doesn't include them with mixed case, as that has solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: files are always lowercase, classes always camelized

Comment: Why do you even try to require SecureRandom? Various bits of Rails [already depend on SecureRandom](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=require+securerandom+path%3Aactivesupport%2Flib&type=Code) and require it for you.

Comment: @apneadiving That is not true, the usual convention is to use all lowercased filenames (whether to use dashes or underscores (or nothing at all) to mark an inner majuscule seems to be… undefined…); and the *only* requirement for Ruby classes/modules is a capital letter at the beginning.

Comment: @DMKE, the short answer is I didn't know, and just checked and you're right. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @DMKE yes you're right :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The actual name is `securerandom`, all lowercase. Linux filesystems are usually case sensitive.

So, change your require to:

```
require 'securerandom'
```

Comment: We should respect the fact: camels love to camelize

Comment: That did it, thank you! And it looks like Heroku is on Linux, while I am on Unix locally, so that may be why it only failed when I pushed. Any ideas why modules are declared in mixed case and required in lowercase?

Comment: Class and module names in ruby should always be declared in camel case, but you're not requiring the class, you're requiring the file where the class is declared. The actual file name should have been `secure_random` but for some reason they decided to use [securerandom](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html).

Comment: And @apneadiving, does this make me a camel?

Comment: are camelizers camels? :) actually I was so biased I didnt notice you're actually a girafe!

Comment: thanks. I was having trouble because I expected SecureRandom to be required as 'secure_random'